# Multiple File uploads on the same page using Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, nodes

I have a registration page where I want to test file uploads, one is to upload proof of address, the other is for proof of I.D.
I'm able to upload a file through the first file upload but I'm not sure how I'm to get it upload for the second file upload.
The HTML/CSS isn't designed by me so I'm not sure how to distinguish between either file upload.

This is the HTML for the two different file uploads

```html
<input type="file" required="" class="form-control ng-invalid" ng-class="{'ng-invalid':!user.files.id.file, 'submitted':invalid}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().applyFileToScope(this.files,1)">


<input type="file" required="" class="form-control ng-invalid" ng-class="{'ng-invalid':!user.files.id.file, 'submitted':invalid}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().applyFileToScope(this.files,1)">
```

This is my Protractor code for the file upload:

```js
var path = require('path');
 var fileToUpload = '../sql.txt';
 var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
 element.all(by.css('input[type="file"]')).then(function(items) {
   items[0].sendKeys(absolutePath);
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `items[1].sendKeys(absolutePath)` for second input?

Comment: Thanks a million, that works!